# where the core.js library is included in cscart

Tags: javascript, cs-cart

Where the core.js library is included in cscart

I have a doubt in checkout procedure

In checkout procedure customer has entered the billing and shipping address in step_two.tpl after entered when he clicks on continue it checks the form fields are filling properly are not,if not displays error messages....

I wrote some additional code for checking the address where he entered the proper address or not.This functionality is working when the user clicks on the "continue" button. I wrote the code in document.ready function,i get the proper address from usps library and displays the suggested address if user entered any thing wrong...

### My requirement is:

When user clicks on "continue" button my "address verification" validation is working first then the cscart default validations are performed.
I want to perform "cscart default validations" first then my "address verification" validations.

I checked the core.js library in that "this.check = function()" performs the form fields validations and get the response(true/false) to "check_fields_result" variable.

If I can get that "check_fields_result" variable value in step_two.tpl. If possible I can run my "address verification" validations with the following response of that variable
(or)

How can I call manually (this.check = function()) this function in step_two.tpl

Can you explain the steps how that core.js library is included when "continue" button is pressed in step_two.tpl?

Answer (score 0):

Form validator checks all form on "submit" event.

```
// core.js
form.on('submit', function(e) {
    ...
    return _check(form, clicked_elm);
}
```

There is some interesting place in the "_check" function:

```
if (!clicked_elm.hasClass('cm-skip-validation')) {
```

So you can add this class (cm-skip-validation) to your submit button and call this function manually (add new "submit" event listener as well)